# Value gets checked in one cell instead of the whole colum

Tags: python, csv

so I was working on some code but I ran stuck on a code. What I want to get is that the code checks if a cell has a value between 0.2 and 2.0 (0.2 < x < 2.0). And if thats true then it should print a word, it should do this for all the cells.

My code now doesnt have any errors but it doesnt work like it should. It checks if the first cell its value is between those two and if thats true it prints a word 344 times (amount of rows in the CSV file).

I tried to name the cell and increase the value by 1 each time it goes through the loop but it didnt work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pygef.gef import ParseGEF

#Read *.gef file
gef = ParseGEF("./CPT000000052185_IMBRO_A.Gef")

gef.df.to_csv("./CPT000000052185_IMBRO_A.GEF")
file = pd.read_csv("./CPT000000052185_IMBRO_A.GEF", usecols=['friction_number' , 'depth'])
print (file)

FrictionNumber = file.friction_number
print (FrictionNumber)
FrictionNumber.dtypes

for i in FrictionNumber:
    if (0.2 < FrictionNumber [0] < 2.0):
        print ("Gravel")
```

This returns:
Gravel
Gravel
Gravel
etc (344 times in total).

How can I make it jump to the next cell so it doesnt only check the first cell 344 times?

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you are only checking for the first row

`if (0.2 < FrictionNumber [0] < 2.0):`

try using your counter `i`.

`if (0.2 < FrictionNumber [i] < 2.0):`

Comment: I did this and it does show the value of the first cell, but now it returns an error: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [1.4986376021798364] of <class 'float'>. Am I right that this says that it should be an integer instead of a float? and how could I solve this